# C++ Домашнее задание (задача)

Tags: c++, vector

### Задача:

> **Условие:**
> Петя успевает по математике лучше всех в классе, поэтому учитель задал ему сложное домашнее задание, в котором нужно в заданном
> наборе целых чисел найти сумму всех положительных элементов, затем
> найти где в заданной последовательности находятся максимальный и
> минимальный элемент и вычислить произведение чисел, расположенных в
> этой последовательности между ними. Так же известно, что минимальный и
> максимальный элемент встречаются в заданном множестве чисел только
> один раз и не являются соседними. Поскольку задач такого рода учитель
> дал Пете около ста, то Петя как сильный программист смог написать
> программу, которая по заданному набору чисел самостоятельно находит
> решение. А Вам слабо?
>
> **Входные данные:**
> В первой строке записано единственное число N (N≤15) — количество элементов массива. Вторая строка содержит N целых
> чисел, представляющих заданный массив. Все элементы массива разделены
> пробелом. Каждое из чисел во входном файле, в том числе и N, не
> превышает 20 по абсолютной величине.
>
> **Выходные данные:**
> В единственную строку нужно вывести два числа, разделённых пробелом: сумму положительных элементов и произведение
> чисел, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным элементами.
> Значения суммы и произведения не превышают по модулю 10^6.

---

### Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, mx, mn, sm = 0, pr = 1;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> now(n);
    cin >> now[0] >> now[1];
    if (now[0] >= now[1]) {
        mx = 0;
        mn = 1;
    } else {
        mx = 1;
        mn = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> now[i];
        if (now[i] > mx)
            mx = i;
        if (now[i] < mn)
            mn = i;
        if (now[i] > 0)
            sm += now[i];
    }
    for (int i = mn + 1; i < mx; ++i)
        pr *= now[i];
    cout << sm << " " << pr;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Код проверил на нескольких примерах - работает, но тестирующая системе его не принимает: *неверный ответ*. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Ваш код будет обязательно требовать хотя бы два элемента массива, хотя мы модем ввести `N = 1` и потребовать лишь один элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уфф, наконец-то разобрался:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, mx = 0, mn = 0, sm = 0, pr = 1;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> now(n);
    cin >> now[0]; // как говорил @4500zenja
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> now[i];
        if (now[i] > now[mx]) // было: now[i] > mx - я сравнивал элемент с индексом
            mx = i;
        if (now[i] < now[mn]) // было: now[i] < now[mn] - то же самое
            mn = i;
        if (now[i] > 0)
            sm += now[i];
    }
    for (int i = min(mn, mx) + 1; i < max(mx, mn); ++i) // как и говорил @MBo
        pr *= now[i];
    sm += now[0] > 0 ? now[0] : 0; // также по ответу @MBo
    cout << sm << " " << pr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1: У вас не учитываются в сумме два первых элемента

```
sm += now[0]>0?now[0]:0;
sm += now[1]>0?now[1]:0;
```

2: Вы почему-то считаете, что индекс максимума всегда больше индекса минимума

```
for (int i = min(mn, mx) + 1; i < max(mx, mn); ++i)
```

Comment: ```now[0]>0?now[0]:0``` - поясните, пожалуйста, что делает данный фрагмент кода?

Comment: Это тернарный оператор, возвращает первое значение, если условие выполняется. В общем, здесь то же самое, что ` if (now[i] > 0)            sm += now[i];`